# .pyc files and naive encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I have a fairly naive thing I want to do and I want to know if someone can answer can tell me if this is just flat out stupid. If what I am going to ask is not stupid but perhaps naive, I'd appreciate if I can get a nudge in a correct direction.

I have a file named *pwds.py*. Its contents are

```
import hashlib
class Pwds:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def printGood(self,key):
        y = hashlib.sha1()
        y.update(key.encode('ascii'))
        if y.hexdigest() == "db5f60442c78f08eefb0a2efeaa860b071c4cdae":
            print("You entered the correct key!")
        else:
            print("Intruder!")
```

Then I have another file named *runme.py*, whose contents are

```
import pwds
x = input("Please type the password: ")
y = pwds.Pwds()
y.printGood(x)
x = input("Press any key to end")
```

The first time *runme.py* is run, a *pwds.pyc* file is created. My thought was that once the *.pyc* file was created, I could delete *pwds.py* and run *runme.py* as normal. Additionally, I thought the contents of *pwds.py* would be contained in *.pyc* but made unreadable since this is a "compiled" Python file. Thus, while I can delete *pwds.py* and successfully run *runme.py*, *pwds.pyc* is pretty much readable if I open it in, say, Notepad.

Thus, the question(s) in general: How can I keep the contents of *pwds.py* unreadable? What I wanted to do with the above code was to keep "secret" information in a Python file, compile it, and have its contents be accessible only if the correct key were typed. Is this approach too stupid to even consider? I didn't want to get into writing a "garbler" and a "degarbler". I thought this would be a simple and cheap solution.

Thanks for reading this! Please let me know if there is any other information I should provide.

Comment: What do you have to hide? A HASH value? Its extremely hard to find something that will hash to that value even if you know it...

Comment: i don't want to hide the hash. i used the hash because i thought it would be silly to type in the password in pwds.py. i want the statements in the if-statement to be visible only if the correct key is entered. but i don't want someone just opening up the file and reading the contents within the if-clause either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .pyc file simply contains the compiled python code so it doesn't need to be recompiled everytime you run your program. Thus all strings in it are still readable (you could always look at the binary contents or step through the program via the pdb debugger).

If you want to protect something in your code with a password, you have to **encrypt** it with strong encryption and only store the encrypted version. The users's key/password is then used to decrypt the data.

Comment: You might want to look at PyCrypto.

Comment: thanks. sorry for the delay in marking the question as answered.